# owl-carousel custom dots without changing owl-theme default CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I'm working with owl-carousel and I want to customize the navigation.I don't want to change default `owl-theme.css` .because for some other sections I want this default functionality also.If I customise default `owl-theme.css`. I get the output but it conflicts with all sections.
So far I tried to like this here the overview of the code.

**In js**

```
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    dotsContainer: '.slider-nav .thumbs'
});
```

Here i define saperate div in html for cutomizing dots and in css like this

```
.slider-s1 .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot {
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline; }
.slider-s1 .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  background: #D6D6D6;
  display: block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
  border-radius: 30px; }
```

But its not working.
Can anyone suggest me how I will do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You only want to change dots? So first in js, you need update `options` then you should override `css`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried that but a very simple solution would be to create a clone of the css file just for that page and make the changes in it, but if for some reason you can't do that, reinitialize the owl carousel on that page and add required code